# Compliling Visual Studio 6 C project from git bash

Tags: makefile, git-bash, visual-studio-6

I'm trying to automate builds of Visual Studio 6 projects (written in C). I can build the project (.dsp) with the following command from the windows console:

```
msdev reg.dsp /make "reg - Win32 Release"
```

But I cannot do this from the GIT bash. What it does is just open the project in visual studio, and report a following error:

```
C:/Program Files/Git/make
File not found.
Please verify that the path and the file name are correct.
```

sh --version says the following:

```
GNU bash, version 3.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

So, how can I build a Visual Studio 6 C project in GIT Bash console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something weird happens when I send `/` (slash) parameters in git bash on windows. I replaced those with a `-` (dash/minus), so the build command looked like the following, and it finally worked:

```
msdev reg.dsp -make "reg - Win32 Release"
```

And within a shell script it look like this (in case someone finds this to be useful):

```
command="msdev ../reg.dsp -MAKE \"reg - Win32 Release\""
eval $command
```